# If an iframe has role="presentation" is a title attribute still required for accessibility purposes?

Tags: iframe, accessibility, recaptcha, wcag, wcag2.0

We are using Google reCaptcha for our web forms. I recently ran an accessibility scan on our web forms and the scan is flagging a new error -- the reCaptcha is using an iframe that does not include a title attribute. However, the reCaptcha iframe does have role="presentation". If an iframe has role="presentation", is a title attribute still required for accessibility purposes? The relevant guideline is WCAG 2.0 A 2.4.1.

Comment: I'm of the opinion that this is either a false positive or it's a thing Google has to change (good luck getting them to do that). Also dealing with this at the moment and trying to tell the QA person that I can't change it is like talking to a block of wood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT** (thanks to @andrewmacpherson): The `iframe` now can have the "presentation" role, but you still need an empty `title` attribute for non-ARIA technologies

**Original answer:**

`iframe` can't have the "presentation"  role.

According to [Document conformance requirements for use of ARIA attributes in HTML](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-aria/#docconformance), they are restricted to `application`, `document`, or `img` roles.

That being said, you should always use the `title` attribute for `iframe` elements for assistive technologies not using ARIA.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, the iframe code is being generated by Google's external JavaScript file, so I don't have direct control over it.

Comment: The document linked to here is still a working draft, and it appears to have changed since then. According to the current version of [ARIA in HTML (14 December 2018)](https://www.w3.org/TR/2018/WD-html-aria-20181214/), iframe can have the presentation role.